# Byte place holder?

Tags: c#, byte, placeholder

Hey guys I'm working on a project in C# were I must replace any byte that will terminate a string with some sort of place holder.. Is there some way to do this in C# without terminating the string or interfering with the data at hand?

The reason i need to do this is because I need to put the bytes in the same spot after.

Comment: Anything that can be replaced for 0x0 that will show up in the byte array but be ignored if converted to a string.

Comment: What on earth you want to do that?

Comment: Because this particular, non-public format contains many files in it and uses null bytes towards the middle of each file (in the file)  which needs to be removed when converting it to a string to be edited. They need to then be inserted after in the same location. The size of the file in whole cannot be changed.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the null byte entirely, and mark its position('s). Then, when you are rebuilding the byte array, reinsert it. It may be easier to use lists (insert at, and remove at), and just convert to afterwards to the byte array format.

Comment: @user556396, does "I suppose I could make this work" mean that it didn't actually solve your problem?